# INavigationAware can't navigate away

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm using Prism Unity, I have an abstract RecordViewModel : BindableBase, RecordListViewModel : RecordViewModel, and RecordUpdateViewModel: RecordViewModel, INavigationAware. There is also a separate Navigation Module and my MainWindow has 2 regions, NavigationRegion and ContentRegion. All RecordViews reside in ContentRegion. For whatever reason, whether I make a GoBack button or click on a button in the NavigationRegion, I cannot leave the Update view. I have narrowed down that the problem is in the ViewModel and that I'm missing something for INavigationAware. Please tell me what I'm missing or did wrong, thank you.

```
public class RecordUpdateViewModel : RecordViewModel, INavigationAware
{
    private IRegionNavigationJournal navigationJournal;

    public RecordUpdateViewModel(IRecordService context) : base(context)
    {
    }

    public bool IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return false;
    }

    public void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        //irrelevant to problem logic to bring in Record.Id

        navigationJournal = navigationContext.NavigationService.Journal;
    }
}
```

**Edit**

Just incase I screwed up elsewhere here's my registrations in the module.cs

```
container.RegisterType<IRecordService, RecordService>();

container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<RecordListView>();
container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<RecordUpdateView>();

regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", typeof(RecordListView));
regionManager.RegisterViewWithRegion("ContentRegion", typeof(RecordUpdateView));
```

I navigate to the views with regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "RecordUpdateView", parameter) and if I don't use INavigationAware on the UpdateView, all buttons work, but when I put it back on I can't navigate away.

**Edit2**

Here is the XAML for the ListView that navigates to the UpdateView and the bound command

```
<UserControl x:Class="App.Record.Views.RecordListView"                  
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True">
    <DockPanel>
        <WrapPanel>
            <Button Content="Edit"
                    Command="{Binding EditCommand}"/>
        </WrapPanel>
        <DataGrid>
           <--Irrelevant-->
        </DataGrid>
    </DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Command

```
private DelegateCommand editCommand;
public DelegateCommand EditCommand => editCommand ?? (editCommand = new DelegateCommand(EditRecord));

private const string RecordID = "RecordID";
void EditCommand()
{
    var parameter = new NavigationParameters();
    parameter.Add("RecordID", SelectedRecord.ID);
    regionManager.RequestNavigate("ContentRegion", "RecordUpdateView", parameter);
}
```

Commands for the Navigation menu buttons work the same, and any view not using INavigationAware can be navigated away from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall hang my head in shame... look to the OnNavigatedFrom... and all 3 INavigationAware Members for anyone else that looks to this... and remove the NotImplementedExceptions that are auto generated. If you don't need that void, it has to be there so INavigationAware doesn't yell at you for not fully implementing it, but there doesn't have to be any logic in those voids if you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

[INavigationAware](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.prism.regions.inavigationaware(v=pandp.50).aspx) has nothing to do with navigating from view to view. It simply give you an easy way to pass parameters between the view. I think what you're looking for is something called [IRegionManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.composite.regions.iregionmanager.aspx) then you can do somehting like `regionManager.NavigateTo(regionName,viewName)` you will have to register the view with your container.  Something like `container.RegisterType<object,Views.View>(ViewNames.ViewName);` and of course `ViewNames.ViewName` is a constant string with the name of the view.

Comment: I edited my question to give more detail, I do think INavigationAware is what seems to be not quite right but hopefully more snippets will lead someone to the problem.

Comment: can you please add the xaml?

Comment: I added more snippets, are you thinking my commanding is wrong?

Comment: no, I think that you need to register your region. I think that your region should look like `<ContentControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static constants:RegionNames.MyRegion}"></ContentControl>`

Comment: and then call `regionManager.RequestNavigate(regionName,viewName);`

Comment: That ContentControl part is in my MainWindow.xaml one for the NavigationRegion, one for the ContentRegion. Only difference between yours and mine is I didn't constant the names... that's not going to fix anything but sounds like good practice and I'll do that anyway.